# Why should url-pattern in servlet mapping start with forward slash(/)

Tags: java, servlets, url-pattern, servlet-mapping

I was reading Head First JSP and Servlets book. I was going through the mapping of servlet. And my doubt here is

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.avinash.TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ServletBeer.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

1. Why should the `url-pattern` start with forward slash(`/`)?
2. What does the forward slash(`/`) represent? Does it represent our webapp name?
3. What happens if the `url-pattern` do not start with forward slash(`/`)?
4. Is it a specification to start with forward slash(`/`)?

And in the book it is clearly mentioned:

> Don't forget the forward slash(/) in the url-pattern.

Can you explain?

Answer (score 7):

The `/` in the url-pattern means the root of the web application that uses this web.xml. So when you give `/ServletBeer.do`. That means `http://<yourhost>:<port>/<your context Root>/ServletBeer.do`. When ever you hit this url, the servlet you which have mapped with this i.e `com.avinash.TestServlet` will be invoked.

Its not mandatory that you have to use `/` in all your url mapping - that purely depends on how you want to configure it. `/` is just a regular expression. You can also use `*.jsp` in your url-pattern - which will actually invoke this servlet everytime you request any jsp in your web- application. 
Consider the section **12.2 Specification of Mappings ** from **JSR-000315 Java Servlet 3.0 Final Release**

> 12.2 Specification of Mappings In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define mappings:
>
> ■ A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’
>   suffix is used for path mapping.
>
> ■ A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension
>   mapping.
>
> ■ The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to
>   the application's context root, i.e., requests of the form
>   `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`. In this case the path info is ’/’
>   and the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).
>
> ■ A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default"
>   servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
>   request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
>
> ■ All other strings are used for exact matches only

Comment: The / in the url-pattern means the root of the web application that uses this web.xml. One small doubt .You mean to say if my webapp is deployed in the folder Beer-app. So are you referring Beer-app as the root of the web application

Comment: lets say your Beer-app is the folder deployed under tomcat/webapps. then Beer-app will be your root of the app. Please accept if the above answer is what you were looking for

Comment: As you said http://<yourhost>/ServletBeer.do. When i hit the url as http://localhost:8083/ServletBeer.do  i get HTTP Status 404 - /ServletBeer.do. My application is in beerV1 folder, Should the url be http://localhost:8083/beerV1/ServletBeer.do. And when i access the url as follows http://localhost:8083/beerV1/ServletBeer.do i get the output. I mean to say the expected servlet is hit and i can see the output

Comment: yep, updated I missed the context root. In your case beerV1 is to context root

Comment: The official reference is already given. Great! Have to thump up for @shikjohari

Answer (score 0):

On the above questions i could find answer for one of the questions.

What happens if the url-pattern do not start with forward slash(/). I have checked it but i don't remember

When i started tomcat by removing the / in the url-pattern i got the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> ServletBeer.do in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3242)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1324)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1348)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:880)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5343)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

This indicates that if we are not using extension mapping compulsory the url-pattern should start with /

Comment: The other question which i figured out was 2. What does the forward slash(/) represent. Does it represent our webapp name. The slash(/) represents the context root of the web app.