# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> coreservlets.ShowItems_ArrayList

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, url-pattern

Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 1

Build id: 20130919-0819

> Steps taken so far:
>
> (1) Deleted the .snap file located in the directory
>
> ```
> <workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources
> ```
>
> (2) Deleted tmp folder in the following directory
>
> ```
> <workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core
> ```
>
> (3) Clean project & server
>
> (4) Reconfigured the server by deleting the current server, & adding
>   new server
>
> (5) Just to ensure changes to reflect, restarted Eclipse every time
>   after performing above steps.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> coreservlets.ShowItems_ArrayList in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3254)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1430)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

However, all the tips & tricks seems to have gone in vain.

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ShowItems_ArrayList</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>coreservlets.ShowItems_ArrayList</servlet-class>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ShowItems_ArrayList</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>coreservlets.ShowItems_ArrayList</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: seems the problem is `Invalid <url-pattern>` thing. could you post your web.xml here?

Comment: **web.xml file**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>ShowItems_ArrayList</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class> coreservlets.ShowItems_ArrayList     </servletclass>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ShowItems_ArrayList</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>coreservlets.ShowItems_ArrayList</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>`

Comment: @kucing_terbang - **`web.xml file is attached per your request.`**

Comment: well, you could change the url pattern by adding slash (like what Necreaux has posted)

Answer (score 0):

Your url-pattern is not in the correct format. It needs to start with a slash. While not an exact duplicate, see this question:

[Why should url-pattern in servlet mapping start with forward slash(/)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315618/why-should-url-pattern-in-servlet-mapping-start-with-forward-slash)